# ¿Cómo se conjugaba antes el verbo "afeitar"?

Tags: verbos, historia, conjugación

En el DLE, en la entrada [**afeitar**](https://dle.rae.es/afeitar), se recoge que la **conjugación actual** de *afeitar* es como la del verbo *peinar*.

[image]

Esto implica que antes tenía una conjugación diferente.  ¿Cómo era esta?

Answer (score 1):

Según el mapa de diccionarios de la RAE, en 1780 el diccionario incluía los verbos afeytar y afitar, sin aparecer el verbo afeitar. Dado que los 2 primeros verbos han desaparecido con sus conjugaciones (*...aféytase el uno al otro...* de la 2da parte del abecedario espiritual de Francisco de Osuna, *... nunca mas se afeyto...* El Scholástico de Cristóbal de Villalón, por ejemplo, siendo ambas obras anteriores a 1550) se hace la aclaración en el diccionario actual en caso que alguien quiera tomarse alguna licencia ortográfica y *afeytar* su escrito.

PD. De todas maneras, el verbo afeitar ya era más utilizado hacia el siglo XVII, el motivo para dejar en el diccionario el verbo con 'Y', ya es una consulta más larga.

Answer (score 0):

En cuanto al verbo "**Afeitar**" apareció aproximadamente en el S. XI o XII, después de una larga evolución. La etimología de "*afeitar*" no parece estar muy clara aunque sugiere desprenderse del supino del verbo "affingo" -affinxi - affictum, referido a añadir algo, añadir algo de la propia cosecha, configurar algo, atribuir o poner algo falsamente, inventar... De esta manera el término evolucionará según las modas de cada momento y época, en general se orientará al sentido de la belleza, de los adornos de objetos y lugares, también al adorno de las mujeres, cuando inventan o ponen algo **"*postizo, como cosméticos*"**, sustancias con que se hermosean y realzan la belleza de las mujeres, a los asuntos de los hombres, cuando estos se arreglaban el cabello o la barba mientras cerraban negocios, según las modas de cada momento y época. *Afeite* arreglar con afeites, arreglo con que algo se mejora o se pone más hermoso.

---

Como nota principal indicar, que después de dedicarle un tiempo, y estudiar la conjugaciones y modos de los verbos antiguos, creo modestamente que cuando aparece en el encabezado "*Conjug. actual c. peinar*" (Conjugación actual como peinar) , no se refiere a que la conjugación haya sido distinta en el pasado, sino que el verbo "*peinar*" se ha elegido como patrón, como "modelo" de tipo de conjugación o guía para verbos que tienen la misma **morfología verbal**.  Por ejemplo, se eligen modelos para verbos que presentan en su raíz alguno de los grupos vocálicos /ai/, /au/, /**ei**/ y /eu/.

Por tanto;

- **Por una parte** tenemos un verbo **afeitar** que corresponde a la edición número 22 del Diccionario de la Lengua Española del año 2001. Desde aquí se puede acceder a la definición de "**afeitar**" y desde esa página a otra donde aparece la conjugación del verbo.

https://www.rae.es/drae2001/afeitar

Esta remisión a la "Morfología verbal" de la conjugación actual, como peinar, la podemos encontrar en la edición electrónica del 2001, aunque ya no aparece de forma completa en la versión más actual, lo que puede llevar a la confusión de pensar que existe una conjugación distinta.

[image]

- **Por otro lado**, tenemos el mismo verbo "**afeitar**" actualizado en 2022, que corresponde a la edición número de 23 del Diccionario de la Lengua Española del año 2014 junto con las entradas o reajustes electrónicos habituales que hace la academia para la web. La conjugación del verbo no hay que buscarla fuera, sino que ya viene incorporada en la misma página.

https://dle.rae.es/afeitar

[image]

*Aquí ya solo aparece "Conjugación actual como peinar"*

---

Siguiendo la línea de búsqueda, si acudimos al "**Verbo Peinar**", vemos que este nos aparecerá como "Conjugación modelo".

[image]

*El verbo peinar actúa como conjugación modelo, referida a la morfología verbal*

**Se les llama modelos sencillamente porque sirven como guía para la conjugación de otros verbos.**

---

Añadir como información general que las nuevas novedades en expresiones, verbos y definiciones actualizadas del año 2022 van incorporándose paulatinamente en la web a partir de la edición número 23 del Diccionario de la lengua española que se publico en Octubre del año 2014, ya que la anterior edición del Diccionario de la lengua española, fue publicada en el año 2001.

**Otro Modelo**

Por último y para cerrar este tema, un ejemplo más lo tenemos en el verbo "**mover**" donde podemos hallar la misma ficha en la que leemos "*conjug. modelo actual.*" (**Conjugación modelo actual**), indicándonos que es un verbo cuya conjugación sirve igualmente de modelo para otros verbos.

[image]

---

---

---

**Notas sobre la Conjugación Antigua del Verbo Afeitar**

A partir de aquí, todo lo que se deriva es una curiosidad o introducción al estudio de los verbos y de sus conjugaciones, para el caso, de que existieran grandes variaciones en su flexión con respecto al presente y fueran dignas de ser tenidas en cuenta.

Así que por lo que percibí, el verbo "*afeitar*" en español no tiene una conjugación especial o distinta, más allá de los cambios propios que los verbos en general poseen en épocas pasadas.

Por tanto en líneas generales, se puede decir que no ha habido grandes cambios en la conjugación verbal desde Nebrija, si bien en algunos casos, como se ha indicado, la grafía del vocablo "afeitar" tuvo varias modificaciones que no afectaron a los modos verbales, si bien el significado pudiera variar en cuanto a los contextos en que éste se presentara, aunque lo más común era referirse para embellecer algo (un jardín, una puerta, un altar...), a un adorno, a los adornos o cosméticos de mujeres, a la manera de rasurar o tonsura, y a ciertos asuntos.

[image]

*Nebrija Diccionario 1495 "Afeitar"*

[image]

*Diccionario de la Real Academia Española 1770, donde aparecen distintos significados de afeitar con la grafía afeytar*

En este sentido y como peculiaridad, seguiré al verbo "**afeitar**" como pauta o guía a través de los principios de la gramática de 1771 de la Real Academia Española, ya que la Gramática de Nebrija, más alejada en el tiempo, no aporta cambios sustanciales para tenerla en cuenta a la hora de aproximarse a la conjugación del verbo "*afeitar*" u otros verbos en general.

En cuanto a la cuestión de los tiempos, la Gramática de Nebrija, se encuentra aún en proceso evolutivo ya que por una parte recoge bien algunos de los tiempos utilizados en español procedentes del latín, pero no así los llamados tiempos compuestos utilizados ya en español, describiéndolos como verbos que se mostraban dando un *rodeo* a partir del verbo que enunciaban, por lo que he considerado más conveniente partir de esta gramática de 1771 algo más moderna y dejar aquella para un estudio aparte.

Donde si he podido notar una diferencia más apreciable de la conjugación del verbo "*afeitar*", respecto al español actual, ha sido en el idioma gallego, que lo dejare como curiosidad, por si desea cotejarlo con el español, pues quizás se ha pasado por alto la influencia del gallego en el español a partir de la zona norte de España, más incluso que otras pretendidas procedencias más alejadas.

---

Como curiosidades generales, el nombre de algunos tiempos verbales era inexistente, algunos tiempos estaban dentro de otros, e igualmente algunas desinencias relativas a la segunda persona del plural se mantuvieron hasta el S. XVII, y que como nota curiosa, en algunos aspectos, aún mantiene el gallego. Pero esto no ocurrió solo con el verbo "afeitar", sino que básicamente afectaba a todos los verbos prácticamente por igual.

---

También en la segunda persona de plural de imperativo omitían la "d" y así se decía; **afeitá** en vez de *afeitad*.

Para la Gramática del XVIII había tres tiempos **Presente, Pasado y Venidero** (También llamado Futuro).

Así el presente de verbo afeitar, que denota lo que es o hace, se conjugaría;

**Presente**

Yo afeito

Tu afeitas

El afeita

Nosotros afeitamos

Vosotros **afeitades**

Ellos afeitan

---

El pretérito se divide en tres especies;

El indicativo tenía tres pasados **Pretérito Imperfecto**, **Pretérito Perfecto** que a su vez se dividía y el **Pretérito Pluscuamperfecto**.

- Cuando aquello que se trata considera como presente respecto a otra cosa ya pasada, se llama **Pretérito Imperfecto**. Ejem. *Llegó mi hermano mientras me afeitaba.*

---

En el pretérito Imperfecto encontramos la misma variante en la 2ª persona del plural.

**Pretérito Imperfecto**

Yo afeitaba

Tu afeitabas

El afeitaba

Nosotros afeitábamos

Vosotros **afeitabades o afeitarades**

Ellos afeitaban

---

Si la acción se considera absolutamente y perfectamente pasada, se llama **Pretérito Perfecto**. El pretérito perfecto se divide en **Próximo** y **Remoto**.

El Pretérito Indefinido o Pretérito Perfecto Simple, también recibía el nombre de "**Pretérito Perfecto Remoto**".

**Pretérito Indefinido** o "**Pretérito Perfecto Remoto**"

Yo afeité

Tu afeitaste

El afeitó

Nosotros afeitamos

Vosotros **afeites**

Ellos afeitaron

---

Lo que hoy llamamos Pretérito Perfecto Compuesto, antiguamente era el "**Pretérito Perfecto Próximo**"

**Pretérito Perfecto Compuesto** o "**Pretérito Perfecto Próximo**"

Yo he afeitado

Tu has afeitado

El ha afeitado

Nosotros hemos afeitado

Vosotros **habedes**  o habéis afeitado

Ellos han afeitado.

---

Igualmente, existían casos que no estaban muy claros y el llamado **Pretérito Perfecto Remoto** se solía también expresar con el del verbo auxiliar haber, y el participio del verbo de que se usa como "**hube afeitado**". Nótese la escasa diferenciación entre tiempos simples y compuestos.

Así vale tanto decir; "**Después de que afeite al Rey, me retire**", como "**Después que hube afeitado al Rey me retiré**".

**Pretérito Anterior**

Yo **hobo** o hube afeitado

Tu **hobiste** o hubiste afeitado

El **hobo** o hubo afeitado

Nosotros **hobimos** o hubimos afeitado

Vosotros **hobistes** o hubisteis afeitado

Ellos **hobieron** o hubieron afeitado

---

Por otra parte en las formas compuestas en las que había un infinitivo y un caso complementario, tenían una construcción particular, así con el verbo afeitar se decía;

- **afeitarte he** / Te he de afeitar
- **afeitarte hía** / Había de afeitarte
- **afeitar he** / he de afeitarte

---

Cuando la cosa tratada se considera pasada respecto de otra también pasada, se llama "**Pretérito más que Perfecto**", es lo que hoy en día llamamos "**Pretérito Pluscuamperfecto**". Obsérvese más abajo este mismo nombre en gallego.

**Pretérito Pluscuamperfecto** o "**Pretérito más que Perfecto**"

Yo **hia** o había afeitado

Tu habías afeitado

El **hia** o había afeitado

Nosotros habíamos afeitado

Vosotros **habíades-habedes** o habíais afeitado

Ellos habían afeitado

---

El **Futuro de Indicativo**, que hoy es tiempo simple, se usó como compuesto bajo una curiosa fórmula, para más tarde ensamblarse en uno;

**he de afeitar** - (Yo) **afeitar he** - Yo afeitaré

**has de afeitar** - (Tu) **afeitar has** - Tu afeitarás

**ha de afeitar** - (El) **afeitar ha**  - EL afeitará

**hemos de afeitar** - (Nosotros) **afeitar hemos**   - Nosotros afeitaremos

**habedes de afeitar** - (Vosotros) **afeitar habedes** - Vosotros afeitaréis

**han de afeitar** - (Ellos) **afeitar han**        - Ellos afeitarán

---

**Del Subjuntivo**

Del Subjuntivo se hace notar expresamente el Pretérito Imperfecto", pues los demás no tienen particularidad alguna que hacer notar, sino atender a las variaciones precisas de la conjugación.

Se dice que del Pretérito Imperfecto de Subjuntivo se tienen por equivalentes tres terminaciones que tiene cada una de las personas del singular y del plural, aunque no siempre lo son.

El texto se refería a las terminaciones **hubiera**, **habría** y **hubiese**, que en la época se mantenían emparentadas.

**Pretérito Imperfecto de Subjuntivo**

Yo afeitara o afeitase

Tu afeitaras o afeitases

El afeitara o afeitase

Nosotros afeitáramos o afeitásemos

Vosotros **afeitaredes o afeitasedes**

Ellos afeitaran o afeitasen

La misma primera persona del verbo auxiliar **haber**, tiene las tres terminaciones **hubiera**, **habría** y **hubiese**. En este tiempo el Pluscuamperfecto de Subjuntivo, considerado tiempo compuesto o impropio (*tiempos que se expresan con más de una palabra*) estaba formado de manera compuesta por estas tres formas "hubiera, habría, hubiese afeitado".

El Pretérito Perfecto de subjuntivo era igualmente "haya afeitado" y dentro del futuro estarían las formas "**habré**" y "**hubiere**" afeitado.

Hoy la forma "**habré**" pertenece al **Futuro Perfecto de Indicativo** y no al subjuntivo como antes estaba encuadrado.

En este sentido para entender este apartado hay que decir que en este tiempo las formas **afeitara**, **afeitaría** y **afeitase** se tenían por equivalentes, aunque no siempre lo eran.

Más tarde buscarían una ubicación más racional, así para **afeitara** y **afeitase** encontraron que eran totalmente equivalentes y las fusionaron bajo un mismo epígrafe, el "***Pretérito Imperfecto de Subjuntivo***", pues entre ellas no había duda, afeitara o afeitase, afeitaras o afeitases...

Mientras, la terminación "**afeitaría**", a veces no tenía una misma equivalencia con las otras dos, más tarde pasaría a encuadrarse en el modo Indicativo, con el nombre de **Condicional**.

Para resolver está observación surgieron algunas reglas, como aparecer o no aparecer en oraciones alguna conjunción condicional, si, sino, sino es que, sino es cuando, sin que, aunque... en las que se necesitara de otro verbo en la que apareciera la segunda terminación y que perfeccionaba el sentido de la frase. "*Si yo pudiera (1) o pudiese (3) te afeitaría (2) todos los días*".

Como características de estás terminaciones, que por su variedad en su uso, puedan ser utilizadas en tiempos diferentes, presente, pasado y futuro, por lo que no se pueden fijar límites correctamente. De todo ello resulta que la segunda y la tercera terminación se usan siempre en sentido diferente y sirven para poner de relieve los dos extremos de la condición.

---

---

**Conjugación del Verbo Afeitar en Gallego**

[image]

---

Obsérvense algunas desinencias relativas a la segunda persona del plural, las mismas o parecidas, que se mantuvieron hasta el S. XVII en el idioma español. Igualmente es de notar la formulación que se hace del **Pretérito Pluscuamperfecto** (*Pretérito Mais-Que-Perfecto*) que en español es forma compuesta o impropia, mientras que en gallego es simple, conservando de esta manera el antiguo pluscuamperfecto de indicativo latino con su significado temporal-modal.

Comment: Hola  今夜九 llevas razón. S.E. la voz "afeitar" ya estaba presente en el S.XIII, quizás el uso de "ahechar" fue anterior, ya que a partir del S. XV, "ahechar" toma el sentido actual. Encontré algo interesante en "3 Lusismos o galicismos. El origen de afeitar y coitar/cuitar" https://books.google.es/books?id=VEpADwAAQBAJ&pg=PT19&dq=ahechar+y+afeitar&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjrh7jyiIX7AhVE1xoKHTW2Db4Q6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=ahechar%20y%20afeitar&f=false Hojee algo en la Real Biblioteca de S. Lorenzo del Escorial, pues no me convence del todo la procedencia. Mañana si puedo lo incorporare. Gracias.